# I'm learning JS and need to show this value from input but it returns me a weird TypeError

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function calcular() {
  var txtv = document.getElementById('#txtvel')
  var res = document.getElementById('#res')
  var vel = Number.parseFloat(txtv.value)
  res.innerHTML = `<p>Sua velocidade atual é de <strong>${vel} Km/h</strong></p>`
}
```

```html
<h1>Sistema de Multas</h1>
<input type="number" name="txtvel" id="txtvel"> Km/h
<input type="button" value="verificar" onclick="calcular()">
<div id="res">

</div>
```

And then I receive this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
> at calcular (ex010.html:23)
> at HTMLInputElement.onclick (ex010.html:15)

Comment: General protip: don't put your script in your HTML file. Make a separate file called `index.js` or the like, and load that with `<script src="index.js" async defer></script>` so that it automatically runs after the page is ready for DOM queries.

Comment: No `#` when using `getElementById`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're getting the element by id already as your selector you do not need the `#` in the selector.

```js
   function calcular(){
       var txtv = window.document.getElementById('txtvel')
       var res = window.document.getElementById('res')
       var vel = Number.parseFloat(txtv.value)
       res.innerHTML = `<p>Sua velocidade atual é de <strong>${vel} Km/h</strong></p>`        
    }
```

Comment: but even better to explain it in terms of getElementById vs. querySelector: the first wants the actual id, as the name implies, while the second wants CSS query selectors (which for ids means #id). Also as the name implies =)

Comment: Quite welcome :) make sure you select the question as answered.